# Node js http request goes into deadlock

Tags: node.js

I have used Node js express framework, in one of my function I am trying to call my another servers API by using http.post() method.

Most of times it works fluently. But at random time; when success response comes back from http post, all proceeding request or db operation goes into deadlock. even though Node is running.

So time being to solve this, I need to restart the Node.
 //Imports

```
var async       = require("async");
var request       = require("request");
var wlogger     = require('../config/logger');
```

//function code

```
exports.sendNotification = function( req, res, next ) {
try 
{
    if (req.session && req.session.publish_UserName) {

            var data = {"request":"callback@create","data":{"userId":req.body.userId}};

            var httpReq=request.post({
                headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
                url:     config.api_url,
                form:   data
            },function(error, response, body){

               wlogger.info({userName: req.session.publish_UserName, action: '/sendNotification', requestData:data, responseData :response,responseCode: '200', message: "/ - sendNotification - Notification sent"}); // write in log //
            })
            httpReq.end();
            res.send({"success": true, "status": 200, "message": "Notification sent."});


    }else{
        wlogger.info({userName: 'anonymous', action: '/sendNotification', requestData: req.body, responseData : '',responseCode: '500', message: "/ - sendNotification - Session not available "}); // write in log //
        res.redirect('/accountlogin');
    }
} catch(err){
    wlogger.error({userName: ((req.session.UserName)?req.session.Plan_UserName:'anonymous'), action: '/sendNotification', requestData: req.body, responseData : '',responseCode: '500', message: '/sendNotification catchException - '+JSON.stringify(err)}); // write in log //
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
}
```

}

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Preferably at least the whole function your code snippet is from, as well as the definition/require/import of `request` and `config`.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja this issue comes at random time.

Comment: I found this issue. I suppose to release all db connection/resources before end of request.